# Is it possible to hide the Mime Type and Tags in Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco

We don't want our users editing the Mime Type and Tags when they alter a document's properties. Is there a way to hide them from editing in Alfresco Share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the visibility of metadata properties by having a `share-config-custom.xml` file with a proper [`field-visibility` settings](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/tasks/forms-type-display.html). Something like:

```
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">
   <forms>
      <form>
         <field-visibility>
            <hide id="mimetype" for-mode="edit" />
            <hide id="cm:taggable" for-mode="edit" />
         </field-visibility>
      </form>
   </forms>
</config>
```

Comment: Looking at `WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/share-form-config.xml` it maybe need `cm:content` condition. I updated the answer.